# Will the kernel change the nice value of a process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Recently, from the result of `top`, I found a process's nice value was set as 10.
It seems that the kernel did this, because the process occupied lots of cpu for a long time.

But, as I knew, the nice value was set by user to specify a static priority for a process. And I'm not sure whether the kernel will set the nice value dynamically.

I knew the difference between nice and priority, and searched the answer for this question with google for hours, but did not make it so clear.

Maybe it's a good idea to read the source code of `sched.c` and `top`, but is there documentation about this? It's a bit hard to figure this out from mass of code.

Comment: I have never heard of the kernel changing the nice value on its own. At the very least the scheduler has more direct ways of influencing the priority without going through nice. Maybe some other user or some whimsical cronjob did it ?

Comment: who's the process owner? take a look at the /etc/limits.conf file configuration
http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf

Comment: In the future, consider turning to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) for these types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linux kernel does not automatically change the nice value - something else did it.